# Удаление из множества таблиц по одинаковому ключу

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблицы: a, b, c, d.
Все таблицы имеют одинаковый `FK = IDXXX`.

Возможно ли одним запросом удалить записи сразу из всех таблиц по этому ключу?

Как то так:

```
DELETE FROM a,b,c,d WHERE IDXXX = 'YYYY';
```

Comment: Невозможно. Только если у вас FK созданы с 'ON DELETE CASCADE' и вы удаляете запись на которую эти FK ссылаются

Answer (score 2):

Невозможно.

Если вам необходима целостность удаления, оборачивайте удаление из всех таблиц в одну транзакцию, откатывая транзакцию полностью в случае возникновения проблем при удалении из любой таблицы.

Answer (score 2):

Да, возможно.

```sql
create table a as select 1 id from dual;
create table b as select * from a;
create table c as select * from b;
create table d as select * from c;
```

Вызов хранимой процедуры это один запрос к БД. Поэтому, можно так:

```sql
create or replace procedure deleteABCD (fk number) is
begin
    delete from a where id=fk;  
    delete from b where id=fk;  
    delete from c where id=fk;  
    delete from d where id=fk;  
end;
/
exec deleteABCD (1)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Или так:

```sql
create or replace view abcd as
    select a.id from a join b on b.id=a.id join c on c.id=b.id join d on d.id=c.id;

create or replace trigger deleteABCDTrig instead of delete on abcd 
begin 
    deleteABCD (:old.id);
end;
/

delete from abcd where id=1;

1 row deleted.
```

В обоих случаях, записи из всех четерёх таблиц с `id=1` будут удалены.